# Python: os path isfile check in shared pvc(ReadWriteMany) is returning false negative

Tags: python-3.x, kubernetes

- I create a file in one pod (pod-1) `<folder_name>/file.txt`
- Simultaneously I check if it exist from another pod (pod-2) `<folder_name>/file.txt`
- both shares the same pvc mount path <folder_name>
- When i am using `os.path.isfile(<folder_name>/file.txt)` from pod-2 it returns `False` for a significant amount of time before it actually finds it.
- But if i use `"file.txt" in os.listdir(<folder_name>)` it returns True as soon as the file is created.

I have ran considerable amount of iterations over the same steps every time the result is same. Am I understanding something wrong here or is it a bug in Python os library?

We are using Python 3.9 and Kubernetes cluster version is v1.18.20.

Comment: I encountered same issue and coded up a work around that amounts to waiting a bit. I hadn't realized that listdir might work as an alternative.